# Multi AUTH Laravel 8 web application Login issue(unexpected redirection)

Tags: laravel, authentication, session

I am currently working with the Laravel 8 multi Auth web application.it has 5 types (*admin , ecentre , ccentre ,farmer ,buyer*) of account with different role.2 type user account created by admin (ecentre ,ccentre)  and farmer and buyer account by using registration system in the authentication system. I used the Laravel livewire fortify authentication system.

my problem is one login to any type of account successfully login. Then log out system particular account and log in to the same account with no problem. But logout this account and log in different account with the correct credential do nothing(**login request send but do not login**) and stay on the login page. Then try it again login with the same user email and password successfully login. That is the real problem I have facing. Anyone facing this issue or any idea to solving this problem .**(This issue is independent accentually user type. Every user type have the same issue )**

I Check to inspect network tab both successes fail stage screen shoot

**Failed Attempt Ststus**
[image: Failed Attempt Screenshot]

**Success Attempt ScreenShot**
[image: Succuss Attempt Screenshot]

Comment: it not bowser related problem I try in several browsers on it

Comment: do you have multiple opened tab? or you have tries one browser tab for the whole process ?

Comment: what is your authentication mechanism ? is it cookie-based or token-based ?

Comment: one I try multiple tabs also.I cookies base authentication.

Comment: I check different browser also

Comment: once upon a time, I had this problem, let me think a couple of minutes, to see if i can remember the solution

Comment: is there any http status code with the **failed login response** like 419 ?

Comment: I mean when you open inspect-element network tab, what would be the http response code, when it didnt login at first attempt ?

Comment: some time it shows 302, not fund status code.

Comment: I update with screenshot network tab in both occupation

Comment: @NipunSachinda If you manually implement the laravel fortify then you can check routes, sometime dynamic routes may create some trouble. Try checking with `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: no, i did set up manually laravel fortify into my system

Comment: @Nipoun : are this screenshots happens after **Login POST** request or they are **Login GET** form requests? (because the method is not visible in the picture) ?

Comment: @Nipun : what is dashboard doing ?

Comment: when a user successfully login to the system.user redirect to dashboard page

Comment: 'Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {

     return view('admin.index');

})->name('dashboard');'

Comment: login Post 302 status code and login Get and dashboard GET 200 status code in fail attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may not unset cookies or Session
Use `Session::flush();` to remove all session.Write it log out function

```
    public function getLogout() {
    
    Session::flush();
    auth()->logout();

    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

This might be solve you problem. thank you!!